# WhatsApp chat backup

Tags: iphone, icloud, backup, whatsapp.app

I am confused about how to backup WhatsApp chat message history on iPhone.

I have followed the instructions over at https://faq.whatsapp.com/902477924463699/?helpref=hc_fnav&cms_platform=iphone. As I understand it, this means that WhatsApp will create its own backup of message history in iCloud Drive, with some regular frequency.

However, I also have iCloud backup enable for my iPhone. The question is whether it makes sense to include WhatsApp in the iCloud backup of the full iPhone? Will this conflict with the native WhatsApp setting above?